# Has anybody gotten nft ct subcommands to work?

Tags: nftables

I am trying to transition from iptables to nftables but the `ct` subcommands (`timeouts`, `setmarks`, `status`, `l3proto`, `expectations` etc but expectations are mentioned in the error message) are not being recognized on Fedora 37 which has an nft rpm past version 1.
The list subcommand will also not parse.e.g. `nft 'list ct timeouts'` will not parse nor will `status` or `l3proto`.
NOTE the single quoted subcommand AFTER `nft` are important. Using `ct expectations` does not work either.

NOTE: Man pages have zero examples and redhat and the wiki has only a few. The whole thing is a violation of Unix's usual do-one-thing-right philosophy.

Comment: Missing quotes, like `"` or `'`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes. nft 'subcommands..' is the easiest form.

Comment: Showing some of the configurations/commands that are not working may help others in troubleshooting your issue.  By `ct`, I am assuming you mean `conntrack`, does [this `nftables` wiki on `conntrack` helpers](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Conntrack_helpers) or [this article on connection tracking](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_connection_tracking_stateful_metainformation) provide any insight?

Comment: Clarified ct expectations. Helpers may have worked but I can't access it right now.

Comment: Simple list : nft 'list ct status' or nft 'list ct id' don't work: only expectation, timeout and helper are mentioned in error messages.

Comment: It would be great if you could update the question to show (a) the `iptables` rules you currently have and (b) the corresponding `nft` ruleset you've tried to create.

Comment: It seems to blocking any real use of *iptables* -m contrack. --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED. ....yes there is also NEW ...

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is.  You seem to be attempting to run `nft` commands that are incorrect syntax or attempt to list items that do not exist.  You reference `nft list ct status` and `nft list ct id` which are not valid commands (you can find valid invocations of `nft list ct` in the `nft` `man` pages).  Most `nft list ct` invocations would also require the table to be specified, use `nft list tables` to list any configured tables (if there are any).

Comment: I have edited the question to remove any reference to Non-Fungible Tokens, which was confusing and probably granted you some of the downvotes. `nftables` does not mean NFT-ables; it stands for *NetFilter Tables*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to blocking any real use of iptables -m contrack. --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED...

I'm using the [`nftables`-compatible version of iptables](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/08/18/iptables-the-two-variants-and-their-relationship-with-nftables), aka `iptables-nft` (you run `iptables` commands, but it creates `nftables` rules). If I run:

```
iptables -A example -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Then the resulting nftables ruleset is:

```
table ip filter {
        chain example {
                ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }
}
```

In general, using the `iptables-nft` package is a great way to migrate `iptables` rules to `nftables` syntax.

---

You can do this from the command line if you prefer:

```
# nft add chain ip filter example
# nft add rule ip filter example ct state related,established counter accept
```

And we can see those rules by running:

```
# nft list chain ip filter example
table ip filter {
        chain example {
                ct state established,related counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }
}
```

Comment: OK maybe I am being a little too ambitious. But the point of transitioning is to incorporate the new system's strengths not to have fall on its face while i am trying to discover those strengths. If something is not available from the cli directly , it should be stated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by, "If something is not available from the cli directly , it should be stated". Everything shown here is "available from the command line" if you choose to create rules that way (see my update to the answer).

Comment: Nobody has contradicted my assertion: *nft list ct timeouts* is a valid command so why is being spat back in my face? Hint line 972 of *nft* man page.

Comment: You have made many assertions, both in your question and in comments. I've tried to help out by showing how you can translate iptables conntrack rules into nftables rules, and how you can create those same rules from the command line. I think I've succeeded at that. I'm sorry if you are unhappy with the answer.

Comment: See [this recent bug report](http://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=1d2e22fc0521bcf73ee1f891c291dc1bde47a6bb) concerning the `list ct timeout` command. It looks like there is a patch available.

Comment: OK. Thx. That does answer my question but the problem extends to fedora 38. They really dropped the ball.